# How to access tailwind classes from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, tailwind-ui

I've just started with Tailwind CSS and I am trying to change the color of an HTML element using it.
This is the HTML code:

```
<h1 id="demo" class="text-3xl font-bold tracking-wide text-center">Hello</h1>
```

And, this is the JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "text-blue-600";
```

Regular CSS works but I am not able to access the Tailwind utility classes.

Answer (score 1):

A class cannot be specified as the value for a CSS property.

What you want to do is:

`document.getElementById("demo").classList.add("text-blue-600");`

If there is a class you want to remove, use:

`document.getElementById("demo").classList.remove("text-blue-600");`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest` or use `<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`  but using the tag won't benefit alot so its better to install it with `NPM`

Comment: I already installed those dependencies using NPM

Comment: @kermit Please Follow This https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation